# Given sequence of real numbers with exactly 2 extreme points. Check if a set is compact-totally bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

Given sequence $(y_n)_{n \in N}$ of real numbers with exactly 2 accumulation points being $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

a)Check if the set A={$\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},y_1,y_2,...$} is compact

b)Check if the set B={$\sqrt{2},y_1,y_2,...$} is totally bounded

Any help is valued since i am not sure of how to solve it.

**My solution so far(Probably Wrong)**

> Check if the set A={$\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},y_1,y_2,...$} is compact

As long as we show that A is closed and bounded then it should be compact.

We know that both extreme points are included in the set  then the set A is bounded by those proving one of the conditions right.

Since $(y_n)$ is a sequence that belongs in real numbers then it is close and open. In this case we will use the close set. As for the extreme points as a separate set we know since the number of elements in that set is finite then we know that the set is compact by itself thus closed.

Given those 2 factors we can prove that the set is compact

> b)Check if the set B={$\sqrt{2},y_1,y_2,...$} is totally bounded

A totally bounded set can be covered by finitely many subsets of every fixed "size" (where the meaning of "size" depends on the structure of the ambient space.)
Since we have n elements in $(y_n)$ (meaning finite) then we can separate  the set into smaller  equal subsets depending on the structure of the ambient space
The addition extreme point $\sqrt{2}$ makes this equal distribution of those subsets unequal       meaning its not totally bounded.

PS.
English is not my first language i hope everything in my solution is understood.

Comment: What does "extreme point" mean here???

Comment: @BlueButtefly Reformulate your question so that it is clear what you mean. Accumulation point $\neq$ extreme point.

Comment: @BlueButtefly With the new formulation, neither $A$ is compact nor $B$ is totally bounded, simply because $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not need to be bounded.

Comment: @Andreas so the sequence by its self is not bounded thus making the sets not compact and B not totally bounded?
And in case we assume sth like that (cause the description doesnt give a lot of info) A is  compact and B totally bounded based on what?

Comment: @BlueButtefly Yes. If the sequence were to be bounded, then $B$ would be bounded because boundedness and total boundedness are equivalent on $\mathbb R$. Also, then $A$ would be compact, which is implied by [sequential compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space) on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much for the time and sorry for the misconceptions again.